# How to make sure if everything is valid before submitting?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a HTML5 form and I'm using javascript to validate the form.

I have several 'if's checking the form and if it valid they change a variable ('pass') to true or false. They also display an error message. The problem is that even if just one thing is valid it changes the variable is true and I need it to only make pass true if everything else is valid.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form name="register" action="register.php" method="POST" >
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br />
            <label id="warning_first"></label>
            <br />
            <label>Surname:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"><br />
            <label id="warning_second"></label>
            <br />
            <label>Gender:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other">Other
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Prefer not to say"> Prefer not to say <br />
            <label id="warning_third"></label>
            <br />
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email"> <br />
            <label id="warning_fourth"></label>
            <br />
            <label>Confirm Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="confirmEmail" name="confirmEmail">
            <br />
            <label>Mobile:</label>
            <input type="tel" id="mobileNumber" name="mobileNumber">
            <br />
            <label>Telephone:</label>
            <input type="tel" id="telephoneNumber" name="telephoneNumber">
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel();">
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Register" onclick="submitCheck();">
        </form>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function submitCheck() {
    var pass = false;
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    var genderTest = document.getElementsByName("gender");
    var genderIf = false;
    for (var a = 0; a < genderTest.length; a += 1) {
        if (genderTest[a].checked) {
            genderIf = true;
        } 
    }
    var emailCheck = document.getElementById("email").value;
    if (firstName.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("warning_first").innerHTML = "";
        pass = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("warning_first").innerHTML = "This is required!";
        pass = false;
    }
    if (lastName.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("warning_second").innerHTML = "";
        pass = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("warning_second").innerHTML = "This is required!";
        pass = false;
    }
    if (genderIf) {
        document.getElementById("warning_third").innerHTML = "";
        pass = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("warning_third").innerHTML = "This is required!"
        pass = false;
    }
    if (emailCheck.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("warning_fourth").innerHTML = "";
        pass = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("warning_fourth").innerHTML = "Your email is too short!";
        pass = false;
    }
    if (pass) {
        console.log("OK");
    } else {
        console.log("NO");
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the email is true, the console will log "OK" (which I am using to see if everything is valid"). How can I solve this so that it doesn't 'pass' to true if just the email is valid?

I am using a normal button instead of a submit button because of issues with the @onsubmit.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless. Also, use `<fieldset>` with `<legend>` when you have a *group* of controls (like your gender radio buttons which should *each* have their own `<label>`).

Comment: I used labels just to display warnings for not validating. Should I use something else instead of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, you default `pass` to `false` and change it to `true` if *any* element passes the test.

Reverse your logic.

Set the default value of `pass` to `true`. Change it to `false` if *any* element fails its test.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple, at the start of your code change your pass variable to have a value of 1 like so:

```
var pass = 1;
```

Now change the line of code in your IF statements where you have your pass variable. For a true condition set to this:

```
pass *= 1;
```

And for a false condition to this

```
pass *= 0;
```

This ensures that unless all IF conditions are satisfied your pass variable will not return a true state.